how to make a bijection map of a set of sequences
I don't know to approach this problem. How can I make bijection map for such a set?
Consider the set S of all sequences of natural numbers, such that each sequence
in S has values 0 from some point onwards,
$$S = \{(n_0, n_1, n_2, . . . n_k, . . .) | ∀i∈N n_i ∈ N, ∃k_0∈N ∀i≥k_0 n_i = 0\}$$
Is S infinite and uncountable? Prove your answer.

For $s\in S$, you could define $|s| = k_0 + \sum_{i\ge 0} n_i$ where $k_0$ is the smallest index after which all the $n_i$ are zero. Then
\begin{equation}
S_p = \{ s\in S, |s| = p \}
\end{equation}
is a finite set and
\begin{equation}
S = \bigcup_{p\ge 0} S_p
\end{equation}
Many other choices are possible, for example you could use $\sum_i n_i 2^i$ instead of the above $|s|$.

Who doesn't like my proof? Please explain.
